# Set dashboard as start up page after log in

Tags: jsp, pentaho

I'm new in Pentaho. I want to set my dashboard as start up page after log in. What modification I should make to make my dashboard directly available to the user in the homepage.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Modify index.jsp there's a redirect in there.

Also take a look at CST - Community Startup Tabs -I've used that previously so users can have configurable first pages - Either by username or by role.

Note: The name is a little misleading as you can use it not just for tabs within mantle, but for the initial page too. ( Essentially CST becomes the first page, then CST redirects )